# Choice of mood in a subordinate clause

Tags: mood

Suppose that I wish to use the subjunctive mood in a more or less traditional way.

> I entertain no illusions that my work measured up to the high standard Smith has set.

Should that be "measured" (subjunctive) or "measures" (indicative)?

Why, please?

Comment: I think it would depend on context. The work may have been relevant in the past and is now out of date or superseded, if research, or it could have been architecture, now no longer standing.

Answer (score 1):

In your sentence:

> I entertain no illusions that my work measured up to the high standard
>   Smith has set.

*Measured* is in the [past tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_past_subjunctive) and there is no difference in the form of indicative or subjunctive mood. It does mean that it is a done work and you think that it measures up.

You can make it clear that you mean subjunctive with adding should:

> I entertain no illusions that my work should measure up to the high standard
>   Smith has set.

Or equivalent of this would be the [present subjuntive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_subjunctive#Use_of_the_present_subjunctive) (without the -s):

> I entertain no illusions that my work measure up to the high standard
>   Smith has set.